# How push a file without the folder .gitignore rules to provide

Tags: git, gitignore

Hi i try to push only a file and not the folder where he is located to my repo but i still find no way to do this ..

Is this possible ? If yes or not why ?

Im creating the debug system inside vscode for my work and my lead ask me to only push the file not the folder !

the file is located inside the :

```
.vscode/launch.json
```

i would like to push only the file so in my gitignore i have add the line :

```
**.vscode/!launch.json
```

2 wildcards `*` means is match any file or zero or more directories.

The negation `!` negates (re-include) any file that is ignored by the previous pattern. The exception to this rule is to re-include a file if its parent directory is excluded.

But i still having the folder on my git repository...

Comment: Put the `!` at the start of the line.

Comment: should i let it in front of the fileName too ? @dan1st

Comment: No, just on the start of the file. Note that already committed files are not ignored, however.

Comment: Either your lead is confused too, or you've misinterpreted their instructions, because Git literally can't push a *file*.  It can only push *commits*. Your `.gitignore` problem itself is a duplicate, but if your lead wants the file to be named `launch.json` rather than `.vscode/launch.json`, it's also irrelevant: you have to rename the file so that it's name doesn't begin with `.vscode/` any more, if the file in the commit is to be named without a slash in it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have previously tracked( included) folder , then, the folder has been cached locally by git. To clear the cache, you have to run the below command.

**git rm -r --cached .**

This will help you clear all the local cache .

Hope , I answered your question. Happy coding !

Comment: i git rm -rf the file after each failed attempt !!

Comment: Sorry. Didn't get the point. What was the result after running the above command ?

Comment: git rm -r --cached .  (Don't forget the dot at the end )